# How to restrict user to access particular application from a specific office location in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

While configuring SSO, came across a requirement which says the particular application must be restricted so that users belongs to a particular office location should only be able to access it.

In Azure AD we have the office location in user properties. Going via MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users).However, unable to find a right approach. How can I use the office location from AAD (from user properties) to restrict users to access application from particular office location? Or is there any other ways to do it?

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to create a Conditional Access policy applied to this application, blocking access from all locations, with an exception for the office using the IP address range

[Conditional Access: Block access by location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location)

[Using the location condition in a Conditional Access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition)